# Failed to save IP address changes for network interface

Tags: azure, azure-public-ip

Im trying to add a Public IP to a virtual machine but I received the following error:

> Failed to save IP address changes for network interface 'XXX'. Error:
>   Compute resource VMNAME has a zone constraint 1 but the
>   PublicIPAddress
>   /subscriptions/XXX/resourceGroups/Enterprise_Search/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/VMNAME
>   used by the compute resource via NetworkInterface or LoadBalancer has
>   a different zone constraint Regional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the error suggests - your VM is deployed into a specific zone in a region, whereas your Public IP address isnt. its a regular IP address. try creating a Public Ip address in the same zone as the VM is in and link the VM to that Public IP.

just in case something happens with the comments: Only Standard SKU Public IP can be zone pinned.

Comment: yes! That is what I thougth but both are on "East US 2". Any other idea?

Comment: its about zones, not regions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/availability-zones/az-overview

Comment: pick the zone when creating the public ip, you cannot change it

Comment: I have to created as "standard SKU". This solved my issue! Thanks

Comment: there must be another option. standard sku justs sets a static IP where as you may want to set a dynamic one.

Comment: @Panagiss - did you find a solution to this?  I've just hit the same issue...  I want a dynamic IP address for a VM, but can't create it due to the zone of the VM i'm trying to associate to and don't want a static IP so can't use standard!

Comment: why do you think standard IP must be static?

Comment: @mutex What i think i did is i created a new VM with the same disk, in order to keep data, but the crucial part is after you chose region, to set Availability options to *No infrastructure redundancy required*

Comment: @4c74356b41 because when i select standard sku it disables the option for dynamic.

Comment: If you have a VM with standard public IP and you need move to another subscription, detach Public IP from NIC, move VM and resources to new subscription and later attach a new Public IP. I recommend take a backup before it